# Fit wide table in PDF when downloaded using button from renderDT/datatable

Tags: r, shiny, datatables

I have a shiny app that exports a data table that can be downloaded using PDF, CSV, and Excel "buttons" from `DT::datatable()`. However, the exported data table is very wide, and so the exported PDF is cut off on the right side. Is there a way to make the pdf export in landscape (or otherwise ensure it fits within the page)?

A minimal reproducible example using the `iris` dataset is here:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(DTOutput('tbl'))

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$tbl = renderDT(
    cbind(iris, iris), # example wide table
    extensions = "Buttons",
    options = list(
      lengthChange = FALSE,
      dom = "tB",
      buttons = c("pdf", "excel", "csv", "copy")
    )
  )
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

In `options`, I have tried `orientation = "landscape"` and toggling between `TRUE` and `FALSE` for `fixedColumns`, `autoWidth` and `scrollX`. Based on [this DT help page](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/html5/pdfPage.html) I tried changing the button to `pdfHtml5` (instead of `pdf`) and `extensions = c("Buttons", "pdfHtml5")` (along with `orientation = "landscape"`). Unfortunately none of this worked.

I would prefer to keep within the options/functionality in the `renderDT()` function as opposed to a fresh approach, if possible.